# Yii2 - How to update textInput Value from DropDownList

Tags: yii2

Please I got a problem on Yii2:
I want to insert value into a textInput field based on changes in the selected option from a dropdownlist. Here is my code:

```
<?= $form->field($model,   'course_taken')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Courses::find()->all(),'course_code','course_code')) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'course_details')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

So when the user selects a course from the dropdownlist, the textInput will display the course details of the selected row. Both course_taken and course_details are columns from the same database table.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with help of JavaScript.

**1)** Create action for AJAX request for getting course details by id in your controller and set response format to JSON. I prefer to use [ContentNegotiator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-contentnegotiator.html) instead of setting it right before render:

```
use yii\web\Response;

...

Yii::$app->request->format = Response::Format_JSON;
```

But you can use this approach too as alternative.

```
use yii\web\Response;

...

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'only' => ['get-course-details'],
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $id
 * @return array
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function actionGetCourseDetails($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    return ['courseDetails' => $model->course_details];
}

/**
 * @param integer $id
 * @return YourModel
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = YourModel::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('This course does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Add some JavaScript:

```
$('#select-id').change(function() {
    $.get('get-course-details', function(data) {
        $('#text-input-id').text(data.courseDetails);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Failed to get course details');
    });
});
```

To read more about how work with JavaScript is organized in Yii2, please refer to [Assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) section in the official docs.

Of course you can improve this by adding loading spinner or something like that, etc., but this is just a basic example.

**2)** If amount of course details is small and text also have small size, you can eagerly include it in DOM somewhere, for example in data attribute of option (`"data-course-details" = ...`) and then get it like that:

```
$('#select-id').change(function() {
    var courseDetails = $(this).find(":selected").data('course-details');
    $('#text-input-id').text(courseDetails);        
});
```

**3)** Similar approach to **2)** is to eagerly load data with one AJAX request on initial load and store it in variable rather than DOM.

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function actionGetCourseDetails()
{
    $models = YourModel::find()->all();   
    $list = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'course_code', 'course_details');

    return ['courseDetails' => $list];
}
```

Details are indexed by code so you can easily retrieve it:

```
$(function() {
    var courseDetails;

    loadCourseDetails();

    function loadCourseDetails() {
        $.get('get-course-details', function(data) {
            var courseDetails(data.courseDetails);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Failed to get course details');
        });
    }    

    $('#select-id').change(function() {
        $('#text-input-id').text(courseDetails[$this.val()]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I could not successfully embed the javascript codes. Can you please simplify, as a newbie to javascript?

Comment: @foxychev It's described in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html). And this is a topic for different question, even in that case is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: One more thing, please. I am trying to use the option 3 that you gave me, since am loading data from a model different from that of the form. But I get nothing. i put an alert in between the javascript, it doesn't come up.

Comment: <pre>
$(function() {
     var courseDetails;
    loadCourseDetails();
    function loadCourseDetails() {
        $.get('get-course-details', function(data) {
            var courseDetails(data.courseDetails);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Failed to get course details');
        });
    }
    $('#course_taken').change(function() {
  alert('ohhhh');
        $('#course_details').text(courseDetails[$this.val()]);
       });
    });
</pre>